# Expanding search not expanding

Tags: css, wordpress, search, header, woocommerce

On my website I have a search trigger that when you hover over should expand. I want to keep this trigger in the top left corner. I used this code to accomplish this:

```
.gbtr_tools_search {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}
```

Website:http://museiam.ca/

However, it doesnt expand and starts glitching for some reason. When I remove that code it goes back to the top right and works fine. It works fine on any resolution under 1024px. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: What browser are you getting the error in? This works for me in Firefox on Mac OS X

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome, Firefox and IE11 on Windows 7 at 1920x1080